# How to change the list permission using c#?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, permissions

I have created the SharePoint custom list.i need to give the "Contribute" access for visitor. how to handle this by using c#.
Suggest any idea to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
SPList customList = web.Lists.TryGetList("CustomList");
if (!customList.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{
    customList.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
}
customList.Update();
web.Update(); 

SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)web.SiteGroups["VisitorGroupName"]);

roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor));

customList.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);

customList.Update();

web.Update();
```